# Access named scope dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, named-scope, named-scopes

If I have 3 named scopes like

```
class Foo

scope :test1, ...
scope :test2, ...
scope :test3, ...
```

And a function

```
def x(variable)

end
```

where variable is a string("test1","test2" or "test3")

How can I access the named scope just by knowing that variable's value ?

Something like `Foo.variable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would call `Foo.public_send(variable)`.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it has solved your problem :)

Comment: In 7 minutes :D . Restriction's stuff :))