# Choose scope based on string/symbol without send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

[how to call a active record named scope with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317056/how-to-call-a-active-record-named-scope-with-a-string) and [Access named scope dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000854/access-named-scope-dynamically) have information on how to choose a scope based on a string or symbol, if you're willing to use `send` or `public_send`. I'm rather concerned by the security implications of using those methods, however.

How can I choose a named scope without using `send` or `public_send`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `named_scopes` are normal methods, AFAIK, there is no other way  of calling a method dynamically by the name string/symbol in ruby.

However since your concern is about the security, there are two options.

**1 - Have a private method to dispatch the actual string method name**

This will give your code to control the method name , instead of trusting an outside string. Something like..

```
#Ex: if your method name is 'all', and user sends the string 'All' 

User.send(scope_method('All'))   

private
def scope_method(name)
  {'All' : 'all'}
end
```

**2 - Have a case statement**

Depending on the user string, but this could get **really ugly really quickly**